# How to get many questions in single flow without using the Next button causing server interruption till end of question set?

Tags: feedback, interface

I am working with many questions and want a way by which users don't need to use the NEXT button for every question.

It should be flexible, so that the user can move any where on any question he wants and view a summary of the questions.

Maybe a slider or anything? Please give suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although there are some hints that help to understand your question, it is quite unclear what do you want, can you clarify the question?

Comment: Say there are 400 questions, i want a way by  which i should be able to show him say 5 questions and use paging. But i  want that he should be able to navigate freely to any of 400 questions to be shown to him. This causes the page to grow really large,(i cant use drop down, it wont look good if questions grow )so i want other options for showing the list of all questions.

Comment: why do you want to give constant access to all the questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to PatomaS' comment on your question... :)

How about something like this?

[image]

It allows you to:

- show 5 / 10 / 100... questions per page
- go to a specific question by putting in the question number
- paginate, scroll etc.

If this works for you, you can look at [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for such list implementations.

Answer (score 1):

> But i want that he should be able to navigate freely to any of 400
>   questions to be shown to him.

I'm making a guess, that your users really need to view unanswered/skipped/wrong questions. And if I'm right then you actually need to make a link for filtering out such items.

So a user can click on "Show all skipped questions" and then he will see all skipped questions. Thus he will answer them and click on "I'm done" button to finalise the test.

Answer (score 0):

This was going to be a comment, but got too long, so I'll post it here.

it really depends a lot on how many questions we are talking about, since you want the user to go to any question, that means that all of them have to be present all the time, if you have the titles of all of them, the user, most probably wont read them unless he has to, plus it will be a long page.

If you have, 400 numbers, it may fit on a page, but why would the user click on question 200? or 158? or any number, they don't mean anything. And what would happen if you have 1000 question, that won't fit on a page, not even using just numbers from 1 to 1000.

If you use a method like listing numbers, you could show the summary of the question when the user hovers over the number, but that would also take a lot of time since all the numbers would be visible, consider that you would have to make a ton of AJAX requests to show them.

A slide is not good because you don't have a precise control over it. Plus the more question you have, the less precise it will become.

The only way to give direct access to all the question, would be to show the total number of questions and an input where the user could write the number of the question he want to see. But again, why would the user want to go to a random question?